# Are there any online courses for learning Slovenian?

Tags: resource-request

I am trying to learn Slovenian as I have family who speak it and in all my time visiting them I've never picked up more than a few words.

I'm looking for some online courses that teach Slovenian. It doesn't matter to me if the course is paid or free. The course also needs a basic structure that leads me through the process of learning basic verbs or how to conjugate.

Any help could be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Apologies for the poorly worded question. @Flimzy I do realise I can Google for learning languages - it's just that Slovenian is not as popular to learn as German/Italian/French and the resources in that search are not great for someone who wants to _learn_ the languages - they're for someone who wants to learn phrases for a trip. I'm not sure how I can make the question more specific. If it's not keeping with guidelines then please delete and I'll see if I can post something to the Slavic languages forum once it's up and running!

Comment: @bean: I think there's room for this question on our site. It just needs to be made more specific. Are you looking for online courses specifically?  Free ones? Do you mind paying? Would a tutor work? Do you want a text book? However you can help narrow the question will make it a better fit for us here.

Comment: @Flimzy No, I don't mind paying. I’d just like to pay for something that I believe will be useful! I already bought a piece of software from Amazon but it was much of the same. I’d also be up for an online course. My motivation in asking the question was that since it’s not as popular as other languages it’s not been as easy to find good resources - so I thought that by asking someone who’d perhaps been in my position already may have found some gem somewhere they could share!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Learn Slovenian Online](http://learnslovenianonline.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level=1) seems to be a full-fledged online paid language learning resource. The entire course costs €29.95 and is valid for a lifetime membership. It leads you through the most basic verbs and nouns to reach the fluency of nearly a native speaker. There's also an app for the course, so you can download and listen to audio files of words being spoken by native speakers to help improve your pronunciation.

The same organization also offers [30 minute Skype or in person lessons](http://learnslovenianonline.com/book-slovenian-lessons-on-skype/) for €5, and [60 minute Skype or in person lessons](http://learnslovenianonline.com/book-slovenian-lessons-on-skype/) for €15.

They also sell a [conjugation manual](http://learnslovenianonline.com/downloads/e-book-conjugation-manual-slovenian-verbs-z/) for most, if not all, verbs in the Slovenian language for €7.50.

If you're looking for a more official resource, consider looking into the [Centre for Slovene as a Second and Foreign Language](http://centerslo.si/en/), which offers both online and in person lessons, books, and courses.

Comment: Thanks for these. I'd seen the official one. I hadn't realised it also had online courses. I signed up for one previously and it just had the exams online strangely! The first link looks promising though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Clozemaster has [a Slovak course from English](https://www.clozemaster.com/languages/learn-slovak-online). Taking it as beginner requires some fortitude; might be better to start otherwise. But Clozemaster skills are not completely useless even for a total beginner.

Anki(droid) also has [Slovak decks](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/slovak). I have not tried them.